# how can I display labels on apple watch?

Tags: watchkit, watchos, watchos-3, wkinterfacelabel

**Xcode 8.0**

I try to code my very first app for **watchOS**. I simply want to show a note when pressing the button. Here is what I've got so far:

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation


class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

@IBOutlet var myLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!


@IBAction func getNote(){


    print("button pushed")

    myLabel.text = "here is your note"

}
```

I've tried different approaches already, but really stuck with getting the note on the display. The latest error says "Value of type "`WKInterfaceLabel`" has no member "text""

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `setText` instead of `text`.

```
myLabel.setText("here is your note")
```

Here's the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceLabel_class/index.html)

Comment: omg, it's so beautiful and simple :D  
my mistake earlier was to keep the = instead of the brackets... 
thank you sooo much!!